# Как организовать роутинг в fastify?

Tags: node.js, express, маршрутизация, middleware, fastify

Да простятся мне эти еретические речи, но я считаю `express` лучшей библиотекой для построения api с точки зрения developer experience. Но от повсеместного его использования меня останавливает то, что все кругом твердят (и подтверждают бенчмарками) что express медленный.

Я пытаюсь выбрать для себя альтернативу, но что то ничего не заходит.

Например с помощью express можно достаточно просто организовать приблизительно такую структуру:
userAuthMiddleware.js

```
export const userAuthMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('user auth');
    next();
};
```

adminAuthMiddleware.js

```
export const adminAuthMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('admin auth');
    next();
};
```

setUserRoutes.js

```
export const setUserRoutes = (router) => {
    router.get('/news', (req, res) => res.send(['news1', 'news2']));
    router.get('/news/:id', (req, res) => res.send(`news${req.params.id}`));
};
```

setAdminRoutes.js

```
export const setAdminRoutes = (router) => {
    router.post('/news', (req, res) => res.send('created'));
    router.put('/news/:id', (req, res) => res.send('uodated'));
};
```

userApi.js

```
imports...

const userApi = express.Router();

userApi.use(userAuthMiddleware);
// добавляем обработчики для эндпоинтов '/movies', '/currency-rates', '/whatever'
setUserRoutes(userApi);

export default userApi;
```

server.js

```
imports...

const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser); // как пример мидлвара, который будет обрабатывать вообще все запросы. лень придумывать кастомный

app.use('/user', userApi);
app.use('/admin', adminApi);

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.info(`Express server listening...`);
});
```

Теперь мне очень легко добавлять обработчики в различные "зоны", и эти обработчики пройдут через нужные мидлвары. (Например авторизация пользователей и админов идет по принципиально разной логике). Но этот мидлвар я добавляю в одном месте и больше не думаю про него, он просто работает.

И вот я пытаюсь организовать подобную гибкую структуру роутинга на `fastify`. Пока что-то не получается. То ли документация скупая, то ли я недостаточно внимательный.

Мидлвары fastify, подключаемые через use, получают объекты req и res из библиотеки http а не из библиотеки fastify. Соответственно пользоваться ими не очень удобно - чтобы вытащить что-то из body, это будет целая история.

Приведите пожалуйста пример роутинга в fastify чуть более развернутый чем в официальной доке. Например аналогичный моему примеру с user и admin на express.

Comment: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/